# Make conditional "with" pretier

Tags: python

Any advice on what is the proper 'pythonic' way for the following function. Do I have to split it into two functions?

```
def readSomething(fp=None):
    if fp:
        return fp.read(100)
    else:
        with open('default.txt', 'r') as fp:
            return fp.read(100)
```

---

I need something like this because the `readSomething` function may be called from another function that may or may not have the same file open.

For example, it may be called like this at some places:

```
def doSomethingWithSameFile():
    with open('default.txt') as fp:
         preample = fp.read(10)
         more_data = readSomething(fb)
         ...
```

or like that at other places:

```
def init():
    data = readSomething()
    ...
```

Comment: What Python version are you on?  There is a nicer alternative in 3.4+ ...

Comment: @wim 3.5. What's the alternative?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? The `else` isn't doing anything in this case, since the `if` returns.

Comment: @TemporalWolf, you are right, I can get rid of the `else`. My main concern however is how to avoid the double `fp.read(100)`. Updating the question with why exactly I need thata.

Comment: Also, this is the sort of question better suited for Code Review. [so] is for code that doesn't work.

Comment: how is `readSomething(fb)` better than `fb.read(100)` when you need to read more data?

Comment: @TemporalWolf: the fp.read(100) is just an example. It will be replaced by more logic that I don't want to repeat twice.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]... your example is not representative. And your approach seems needlessly complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is the right solution, but I think it's what you want.

```
import contextlib

def readSomething(fp=None):
    with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
        if not fp:
            fp = stack.enter_context(open('default.txt'))
        return fp.read(100)
```

---

I get the impression that you're going to duplicate this logic many functions like `readSomething()` so I'd recommend putting the ExitStack code into a decorator and wrapping the functions where you need this behavior.

You could also use a decorator. I don't use this kind of code, so the syntax below is almost certainly incomplete, but the general idea stands:

```
import functools

def fallback_to_default(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def new_fn(fp=None, *args, **kwargs):
        with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
            if not fp:
                fp = stack.enter_context(open('default.txt'))
            return fn(fp, *args, **kwargs)
    return new_fn

@fallback_to_default
def readSomething(fp=None):
    return fp.read(100)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's indeed much better version of the one I had, but the double "fp.read(100)" is still annoying me. Any remedy for that?

Comment: Replace both `fp.read(100)` lines with a call to `realReadSomething(fp): return fp.read(100)`? Or use a method to return the file to you... like `getConfFileOrDefault(fp)`.

Comment: @Harvey That doesn't really solve the problem, since you still have to write the same line twice, and now have an additional function to keep track of.

Comment: This exact format can be used with `if fp:`... we gain no simplicity via `hasattr`

Comment: @TemporalWolf: hasattr is a better test than `if fp`, e.g. `readSomething(3)`.

Comment: @Harvey which gives us the _benefit_ of using the default file if you supply something other than a file object, and hiding the true issue (you supplied a string instead of a fp, for example).

Comment: @TemporalWolf Just say what you actually mean.... "Using `if fp` allows the code to blow up on bad input rather than hiding it by reverting to the default file." If that's what you meant, then sure, I agree.

Comment: *There's really no way to avoid calling something twice* <-- that's not true

Comment: @wim: you're right. More like, you either call `read` twice or add a lot of extra code just to avoid one duplicated line.

Comment: How putting the ugly part of the code into a decorator improves anything?  It just moves the same problem to somewhere else.

Comment: It's clear that they're going to use this code in a lot of places so pulling it out into something like a decorator makes sense. I added what OP wants using ExitStack. I updated the decorator to use the ExitStack since I still think they're going to duplicate it.

Comment: The `ExitStack` is a great idea!   If you remove all the clumsy previous attempts, I'd upvote this one.

Comment: I don't use ExitStack often, so I forgot about it. It's handy for calling custom `close()`-like methods using `with`. Example: `HTTPServer().shutdown()`.

Answer (score 3):

To summarise the issue in plain language:

- You may be passed an open file handle, then you want to leave it open, because it is the caller's responsibility to close that resource.
- You might need to open your own resource, then it is your responsibility to close it.

This is the problem with accepting inhomogeneous argument types in Python.  You're allowed to do that, but it can make your code a bit more ugly sometimes.

Context managers are just syntactic sugar for try/finally:

```
def readSomething(fp=None):
    close_fp = False
    if fp is None:
        fp = open('default.txt')
        close_fp = True
    try:
        return fp.read(100)
    finally:
        if close_fp:
            fp.close()
```

To make it any more "pretty" than that, consider to change the interfaces so that you don't have to handle both reading data and doing the resource management from within the same function - refactor to make your functions have a single responsibility.

Comment: This is the right way to do what the OP is asking. It's his specifications which are needlessly complex. and presumably the complexity is from his expansion of the placeholder code `return fp.read(100)` which this reduces.

Comment: It's both more verbose and more DRY, but I don't think more complex - why do you think it's more complex?

Comment: @wim You're typing more of what should be done and less of what you actually want to happen and letting python do it for you. OP's original code (without the `else`) is easier to read, does everything that yours does, and is probably faster.

Comment: But a crucial part of the logic is duplicated, so it's unacceptable.  Even the OP seems to realize that (otherwise they wouldn't have asked the question), and yet you're *still* missing the point.

Comment: @Harvey The OP made the statement: "the `fp.read(100)` is just an example. It will be replaced by more logic that I don't want to repeat twice."

Answer (score 3):

You could define a custom context manager that does something only if None is passed to it, but it might be overkill:

```
class ContextOrNone(object):
    def __init__(self, obj, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        if obj is not None:
            self.obj = obj
            self.cleanup = False
        else:
            self.obj = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            self.cleanup = True
    def __enter__(self):
        return self.obj
    def __exit__(self, ex_type, ex_val, traceback):
        if self.cleanup:
            self.obj.__exit__(ex_type, ex_val, traceback)
```

Or, using `contextlib.contextmanager`:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def ContextOrNone(obj, fn, *args, **kwargs):
    was_none = obj is None
    try:
        if was_none:
            obj = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        yield obj
    finally:
        if was_none:
            obj.__exit__()
```

Once you have this defined, you can define `readSomething` as:

```
def readSomething(fp=None):
    with ContextOrNone(fp, open, 'default.txt', 'r') as fp:
        return fp.read(100)
```

Comment: you forgot to pass `fp` to `ContextOrNone`

Comment: This solution would probably be much better written in the contextmanager generator style. It would be a shorter `try...finally` with a lot less boilerplate.

Comment: @Harvey I guess. Added that variant too, even though it's not 100% equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, the most Pythonic version of your code is probably just what you already have, except slightly cleaned up:

```
def readSomething(fp=None):
    if fp:
        return fp.read(100)
    with open('default.txt') as fp:
        return fp.read(100)
```

That preserves your original intent and functionality. It's clear and easy to read. Sure, it has a little repetition. If your example was simplified to the point that the repeated portion is too grotesque for you, then lift it out into its own function:

```
def complicatedStuff(buf, sz):
    # Obviously more code will go here.
    return buf.read(sz)

def readSomething(fp=None):
    if fp:
        return complicatedStuff(fp, 100)
    with open('default.txt') as fp:
        return complicatedStuff(fp, 100)
```

It's not Pythonic to jump through a lot of hoops just to avoid repeating yourself a little.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use `with`, and closes the default or the file passed as argument,
 but maybe it is still an option.

```
def readSomething(fp=None):
    if fp is None:
        fp = open('default.txt')
    return (fp.read(100), fp.close)
```

Comment: They don't want to close a passed file.

Comment: but the default-file should be closed, as he is using with, right? Was not clear to me from the question, that the passed file has to stay open.

Comment: @user69453 They're only using `with` when `fp` isn't truthy.